# can i get all visited path in react routing without using state or redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

Can i get all visited path in react routing without using state or redux

ex>> im here in routing in "ask"
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/**ask**
if i go to another route 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/**read**

"read"

then to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/**show**

i need to git list of **[ask , read , show]** without using state or redux to store it .(using only react route property/ history )

Is there a library react route that supports this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. Just use `localStorage` for this kind of needs.

```
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';

//Your router initialization

browserHistory.listen( location =>  {
  const previouslyVisitedPaths = localStorage.getItem("visitedPaths")

  let paths
  if (previouslyVisistedPaths === null) { // First write to your localStorage 
    paths = location
  } else {
    paths += `,${location}` // append new path to it
  }

  localStorage.setItem("visitedPaths", paths)
});
```

This code will give you visited paths later:

```
localStorage.getItem("visitedPaths").split(',')
```

Comment: Thank
I'm looking for a library  to do this .Through its properties
Do you think it exists?

Comment: I don't think someone will implement library which is so easy to replace by a few lines of code